# Performance difference between FOR LOOPS with i<n versus to i<=n

Tags: c#, .net, performance

And to a lesser extent, what about a for loop with i<(n+1)? Would (n+1) get evaluated once at start of loop or at every iteration?

```
for(int i=0; i<(n+1); i++){  
   // Do something
}

for(int i=0; i<=n; i++){  
   //Do something
}
```

UPDATE:
As suggested by nearly everyone, I ran a simple test with three loop variations i

Comment: I hope you tried measuring the performance yourself before asking this.

Comment: I think, it should ideally be that i<=n to take less time than i<(n+1), but the implementation would be compiler specific

Comment: I was just wondering if byte codes are different between i<n and i<=n and if that would have an impact. Don't know enough to check this myself.

Comment: Note that the two loops don't actually do the same thing in all cases. Consider the situation where `n == int.MaxValue`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would likely depend on whether or not the value of n was changing over the course of the loop. If not, I would think that any modern compiler would cache the value of n+1, rather than calculating it each iteration. Of course that's not a guarantee, and with no optimizations, n+1 *would* be evaluated each time.

**EDIT**: To answer the title question, i < n vs. i <= n would have no noticeable difference (other than an extra iteration, assuming the n's were equal in both cases.) CPUs have single ops for both comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

I really doubt that would make a measurable difference in the loop execution. Particularly `<` vs `<=`. If you're really concerned, you should [measure it](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/08/why-arent-my-optimizations-optimizing.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is compiler specific, no language standard defines this, though most compilers would try to cache the value (if it's proven to be invariant).

Answer (score 1):

Trust the compiler. Even though the c# compiler + JITer is not as good as the best c++ compilers it is still pretty good.  Unless you determine with a profiler that it is causing a problem you shouldn't spend cycles worrying about these sorts of micro-optimizations.  Instead write what logically matches what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

`(n+1)` will get evaluated on very iteration, assuming it doesn't get optimized out by the compiler.

As for performance issues - this is very easy to measure for yourself using the [`StopWatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class.

I would guess that unless your `i` is very high, the differences would be negligible.